# SBT/Scala and Integration testing

Tags: scala, sbt, integration-testing

While researching on the subject of automating my integration tests, I found out a nice plugin in the maven world called FailSafe. it gives me phases like pre-integration-test, post-integration-test and integration-test.

By tying into these phases, I can have other plugins which can start/stop and run docker images.

The plugin also has a nice way in which I can differentiate between UnitTests and IntegrationTests (even though both are written in JUNIT).

Well now the question is how can I do the same thing with Scala / SBT combination?

my requirement is

1. Write Integration tests in SpecFlow.
2. Integration tests are treated differently than unit tests.
3. First Unit Tests are run.
4. Then docker containers are created and run
5. then integration tests are run.
6. docker contains are shut-down.
7. test results are captured in files. (just like surefire/failsafe plugins).

Is this possible in Scala/sbt combo?

Comment: Sounds to me like you need a CI build system.

Comment: I have one called Jenkins. Currently it executes maven project along with FailSafe integration tests.

Comment: You can have it execute all those steps.

Comment: See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html#Additional+test+configurations and http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Tasks.html.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer to the question. SBT provides means to do integration test and also setup and cleanup methods to do things like creation / destruction of docker containers

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html

Comment: A more up to date link: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html#Integration+Tests

Answer (score 8):

A simple solution is to run `$ sbt "~ it:test"` (make sure integration test are in a package named 'it') for integration test which will automatically run every time source code is updated. Furthermore, `$sbt "~ test"` for automated unit testing. If you are using a IDE such as IntelliJ IDEA, you can make it easier to run this in a custom configuration from the IDE. Hope this helps a little bit. I run these all the time when working.